# new product type image of bundled product - children product price not insert in table sale_flat_quote_item and sale_flat_order_item

Tags: php, magento

I created a new product type image of bundled product and everything is work except the children product cannot insert the price in to database table salt_flat_quote_item and sale_flat_order_item. This turned out to give some problems in the order in the backend cannot show children price of this product. Do i have to call a function to get my children price?

---

this is my config file

```
<catalog>
  <product>
    <type>
      <formula translate="label" module="bank">
        <label>Formula Product</label>
        <model>bank/product_type_formula</model>
        <composite>1</composite>
        <allowed_selection_types>
          <simple/>
          <virtual/>
        </allowed_selection_types>
        <price_model>bank/product_type_formula_price</price_model>
        <index_data_retreiver>bank/catalogIndex_data_formula</index_data_retreiver>
        <index_priority>40</index_priority>
      </formula>
    </type>
    <options>
      <formula>
         <types>
            <select translate="label" module="bank">
               <label>Drop-down</label>
            </select>
            <radio translate="label" module="bank">
               <label>Radio Buttons</label>
            </radio>
            <checkbox translate="label" module="bank">
               <label>Checkbox</label>
            </checkbox>
            <multi translate="label" module="bank">
               <label>Multiple Select</label>
            </multi>
         </types>
      </formula>
    </options>
  </product>        
</catalog>
```

Do I have to create more config or anything to extends bundle product.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I found the problem of this issue but still can't solved. because my new product type cannot insert eav price_type into table catalog_product_entity_int then I test to insert this data in the table by manual and child price of the product insert into table salt_flat_quote_item successful. I don't understand why my new product type is failed, anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Price is calculated from getPrice and getFinalPrice

If its a bundle product it would search the total function of bundle product and calculate the price

As you have created a new product have you created a total model for that i.e. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price

Give us your code details for more information

Comment: Hi Sandeep,

yes I already have some class to extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price and my product can calculate the total price of bundle product. I guess I must create some function in observer file to hook some event before all of my product in bundle product add to quote, but I don't know what event can be answer this problem.